# How pass data from webpage to chrome ext?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

I try to pass *auth_token* to my Chrome extention for use it in GET requests further.

I think it's good if

1. we try to get user from $.get('APP/get/user' {auth_token:''},
   callback) [in my Chrome extention]
2. if we got 'not_auth' response, callback open auth_page in new tab [in my Chrome extention]
3. we login and redirect to the page, which where generate *auth_token* [in my WEB-APP-PAGE]
4. pass *auth_token* to my Chrome extention ????? How? via JS? [in my WEB-APP-PAGE]

How to realize paragraph 4? thank you

Comment: See Google's docs on [content script communication](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication). Content scripts and webpages share the DOM, so DOM events fired in either the content script or the web page are visible to both.

Answer (score 1):

**Good to apsillers**

yes, finally, i GET it!
in my contentscript.js (which load in my token-page) get the token and send it to background

**contentscript.js**

```
$(function(){
  //get token from page
  var token = $.getUrlVar('token');
  if (typeof token != 'undefined') {
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({token: token});
  }
});
```

**background.js**

```
/*button handler*/
function main_click() {
  alert(localStorage['auth_token']);
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(main_click);


/*listener*/
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.token)
      localStorage['auth_token'] = request.token;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `localStorage` of page could act as a brigde between pages and extension.

At stage 3 where the **auth_token** created, dump it to `localStorage`,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 ...
 var auth_token = "sfafsafasfsaf";
 localStorage["auth_token"] = auth_token;
 ...
</script>
```

And get the auth_token in [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) (content.js),

```
console.log(localStorage["auth_token"])
```

Comment: no, page's localStorage and ext's localStorage are isolated. console.log(localStorage["auth_token"]) print undefined

Comment: @Luciuz, sorry but you're wrong, I tried this it's working. you can get localStorage data of current page where content.js is included. But don't forget it must be **a content script**

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome documentation on [content script communication](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#host-page-communication) recommends using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) in the sending code (here, the web page) and using `window.addEventListener("message", ...)` in the listening code (here, the content script of the Chrome extension, injected into the page). Technically, any kind of custom DOM event could also do this, but `postMessage`/`message` already has built-in support.

You should be able to lift the example code from the codes nearly verbatim:

**Native web page:**

```
// right after we get auth_token saved to a variable...
window.postMessage({ auth_token: auth_token }, "http://www.mypagedomain.com");
```

(Make sure `http://www.mypagedomain.com` is changed to your actual protocol/domain.)

**contentscript.js** (in Chrome extension, listening)

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
    // We only accept messages from ourselves
    if (event.source != window) {
      return;
    }

    console.log("auth_token received: " + event.data.auth_token);
}, false);
```

From inside the event listener, you could use [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to pass the `auth_token` to your background page, if necessary.

**EDIT:**

Your manifest should include something like this (note the use of `run_at` below to inject the script before the page loads):

```
...
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://www.mypagedomain.com/*"],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }
],
...
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer, but i cant send (or get) message on document.ready. $(function() { window.postMessage({...}); }) does not work. but after page was loaded window.postMessage({...}); works well

Comment: apsillers, do you know why window.addEventListener "works" only contentscript.js and dont on background.js?

Comment: @Luciuz I added a sample `"run_at": "document_start"` to my answer, which will inject the script before `$(document).ready` fires.

Comment: @Luciuz Content scripts are scripts that are injected into the page. Background pages are separate web pages that run inside your app. You may well ask why firing an event in a page in one tab in your browser isn't seen by another page in a different tab -- they're totally different pages. Content scripts, however, are added to the web page every time it loads.